# Make pyinstaller executable find its own name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, startup, pyinstaller

How do I make a executable compiled with pyinstaller find its own name? I need this to make it copy itself to startup. Or is there another way to achieve this?

**file** only finds the original name of the script, not the executable.

Comment: This sounds like very unusual behaviour. Why?

Comment: More details would be beneficial as your question is very unclear.

Comment: Let's say I compile test.py to no_test.exe with Pyinstaller. How do I make the script know that its own name is no_test.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your problem

```
import os
import sys

# uncompiled file.py can be found by
file_name = os.path.basename(__file__)

# compiled file.exe can find itself by
file_name = os.path.basename(sys.executable)

# and path to py or exe

current_path = os.path.realpath(sys.executable)
current_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
```